# Chrome Command to suppress window

Tags: google-chrome

I need to run a program from a .bat file that uses Chrome.  How can I execute the commanf but suppress any display of the Chrome window?

.bat file command:

start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"  "www.xxxxx.com/shared-hosting-fix.php"

Answer (score 2):

You could get the [Win 32 GNU packages](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) (the [automatic installer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/getgnuwin32/files/) is best). This will include wget. That app makes this easier than Chrome:

```
wget "http://superuser.com/questions/802937/chrome-command-to-suppress-window"
```

Will save this page to a file for example. Or, to save to a specific file. use:

```
wget -O %HOMEPATH%/output.txt "http://superuser.com/questions/802937/chrome-command-to-suppress-window"
```

If you use a dash (`-`) for the output file it will display to the screen instead. Then you can use one of the other tools in that package to further manipulate the file. Unfortunately, these apps are severely hampered by the limitations of DOS. Piping just doesn't work right past the first pipe on Windows.